# How to find if a point is at the intersection of multiple circles?

Tags: math, geometry, intersection

I have a point p and multiple circles C1,C2,C3.... Cn.

How can i find if the point is at the intersection area of this Circles ?[image]

I just know the center(x,y) and the radius of the circles C1...Cn and the coordinates of the point p(x,y).

I have to write a cpp code for implementing this problem.

But at first i need to know the logic. Please help.

Comment: Hint: When is a point inside a circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the distances of the point from the three centers are less of all the three radius.

EDIT: homework? I should not have answered :/